# django queryset with invalid ordering not handling exception

Tags: django, django-queryset

while ordering django queryset with invalid field not raises any exception here is my code

```
try:
    object_list = Foo.objects.all().order_by('zz')#invalid
except:
    object_list = Foo.objects.all().order_by('-id')#valid
```

but it is not going to except block how do i resolve please help?

Comment: I don't see this behavior, you overlooking something else?

Answer (score 0):

I tryed your exemple. An invalid order_by raise:

```
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'zz' into field. Choices are: [...]
```

How do you see it doesn't go in your except block? if you are looking in database logs, nothing will be loaded until you evaluate your queryset.